# I have chat app but when publish in google play they refuse because I must add privacy policy

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play

As you see in title google play wants me add privacy policy inside my app when he create his account
I can build simple site but I don not know what requirement to write
I want to write a formal privacy policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to [blogger](https://www.blogger.com/) site google free blog site.
2. Go to [privacy policy maker](https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/) site choose the services your app uses it will generate
   privacy policy for you.
3. Copy the policy and add to blogger site and get the link.
4. Add the link to your app and play console account.